# AngularJS - can't read the variable's changed value in one of my methods, it returns the old valud

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code like this

```
BackendApp.controller('CustomCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {"name" : "John", "Year" : 18},
        {"name" : "Tony", "Year" : 19}
    ];

    $scope.saveTemplate = function() {
        console.log($scope.names);
        // [
        //     {"name" : "John", "Year" : 18},
        //     {"name" : "Tony", "Year" : 19}
        // ];
    }
});
```

and html

```
<div ng-controller="CustomCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="name in names">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name.name" />
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="name in names">
        {{name.name}} // if we write something in input we see the changed value here 
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="saveTemplate()">Save</a> // when we click on it, we get old value vor the names array
</div>
```

how can i get the access for `names` array in `saveTemplate` method ? :/ it returns only old value for variable

Comment: `name.name` looks weird...

Comment: Hayk I tried to reproduce it , but seems it works correct, I copied your code http://jsfiddle.net/po1pctLx/

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/hgf37bo0/ - your code works

Comment: ooooh, sorry guys, it's my fault, i had a syntax error in html, thank you for your time and response.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your `ng-model`:

Replace:

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name{{ names[$index].name }}" />
</div>
```

With:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in names">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" />
</div>
```

I used `item` to avoid confusion about what variable is what.

Comment: Sorry for wrong description, i have wrote like your code, it doesn't help

Comment: "It doesn't help", so what exactly is happening?

Comment: in `saveTemplate` method i get old value for `names` array, console.log always returns this value 
        `[
             {"name" : "John", "Year" : 18},
             {"name" : "Tony", "Year" : 19}
         ];`, but in view gets value from input

Comment: @HaykAramyan Please provide a plunker to illustrate your problem.